# How to parse JSON in PhoneGap?

Tags: json, cordova

I am implementing a mobile application using PhoneGap framework. I don't know how to parse JSON in PhoneGap.

Can you advise me for that?

Answer (score 7):

This is more a JavaScript than a PhoneGap question.

It should be safe to use `JSON.parse(myJsonString)` since no old browsers are going to be used with PhoneGap.

Answer (score 6):

Phonegap let´s you call to device functions like gps with a simple javascript interface.

To parse a JSON object you can try this two ways:

**Clean example**,

1. first, include jquery, will be more easy
2. make a button with id = "searchButton", a div with id="dataParsed" and a textbox with id="searchBox"
3. include this code:

   ```
   $('#searchButton').click(function() {
   $.getJSON('http://api.alternativeto.net/software/'+$('#searchBox').val()+'/?count=15', 
   function(data) {
   var items=data.Items;

   // uncomment the line to see the structure of the json
   //console.log(items);

   var list = $('#dataParsed');
   list.html("");

      $.each(items, function(key, val) {
          list.append($(document.createElement('p')).html(val.Name));
      });

   });

   });
   ```

**Example of json+ajax+ jquerymobile: Read  this in the phonegap wiki:**

http://wiki.phonegap.com/w/page/36868306/UI%20Development%20using%20jQueryMobile

Good Luck! :)

Comment: how would jquery mobile help him? he's looking for a json parser which is plain jquery or javascript - while jquery mobile is more of a ui library

Comment: At least read the link... there is a working example of json request with jquery...

Comment: I'm sorry, you are right, but I still think it would be more helpful to him to learn what phonegap actually does and doesn't.. since the example is plain jquery and doesn't have anything to do with phonegap or actually even with jquery-mobile

Comment: Again, inside the post it´s explained how to parse json from a ajax request.

Answer (score 2):

actually I think you are little confused, phonegap doesn't let you parse json, you parse json with javascript (like [crokford json parser](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js)  library or jquery json parsing methods) the only thing phonegap does is expose the native api of various mobile operation systems to a common javascript interface.

Answer (score 0):

You can use 2 methods for parsing JSON Data

1. var parsedData = $.parseJSON(yourJSONdata);
2. var parsedData = JSON.parse(yourJSONdata);

Comment: is this for parsing an online JSON. Could you elaborate I am new to cordova