# How to do Json Parsing and plugin integration using Phonegap?

Tags: cordova

I am stuck on Json parsing and integrate any plugin like email, contact us and so on in phonegap. I have done searching many times but not getting proper solution for it.

Please guide me. If you have an sample example then provide me a link which are really working.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to parse JSON in PhoneGap?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7884997/how-to-parse-json-in-phonegap)

Comment: `JSON.parse(Your object)` will give you JSON Object.

Answer (score 0):

Phonegap itself doesn't let you parse JSON. You have to use some sort of library like jQuery and call `$.parseJSON(json)` or just `JSON.parse(jsonString)`. It should be safe to use and supported on all browsers since no outdated browsers are used on the target devices.

Comment: Can you provide me full example?